# My floppy drive in my IBM model 8525-001 doesn't seem to be working

Tags: floppy-disk, ibm

I tried to put a floppy disk into my IBM model number "8525-001" and it doesn't seem to be processing it.

The light below the floppy drive blinks yellow every once in a while (such as when I turn the machine on). I've tried the `dir a:` command to test the drive and only got an error message: It said something like "General error reading drive A:" and I could choose to abort, retry, or fail.

I'm hopeful that the drive isn't broken and I won't have to buy a new one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that the floppy that you are putting into the drive is formatted with a file system that the booted operating system can read?

Comment: Would the drive not be able to tell that a disk is even in the drive unless it is formatted?

Comment: It doesn't make a peep otherwise

Comment: Well that’s weird, `DIR A:` should give you *some* output — either a directory listing, if the disk is formatted and readable (even if the disk is empty), or an error message.

Comment: Check interface cable connected to the drive. May happen that you flipped it around (at the end of the drive or at the end of the controller).

Comment: Ok. I'll see if that's the problem :)

Comment: how long is the floppy unused? (I mean medium not the drive)  it might be demagnetized/corrupted (especially if stored near reproductors,mobile phones etc ...) so the FDC does not see its markers hence general Read error ...  if you got a spare floppy for testing you can try format it just to see if it is working ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`General failure` is a catchall error. If that's the message you're getting, then its possible the floppy you tried is simply not formatted. You could try formatting the floppy disk (Obviously you'll lose anything that's saved on it).

If the floppy is shedding oxide, then that disk is a goner.

If the heads are dirty you may have luck after cleaning them.